# angular maerial datatable is not working though i have the data loaded in my component

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material-6

Using angular 6 and the angular material data table with fetching data with pagination. but I got the data in my component but not rendering in the table. can you please help me where to look?

Html:

```
    <mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="first_name-cell" *matCellDef="let data">{{data.user.first_name}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="last_name-cell" *matCellDef="let data">{{data.user.last_name}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="email-cell" *matCellDef="let data">{{data.user.email}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="active-cell" *matCellDef="let data">{{data.user.active}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [length]="userData.length" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]">
```

TS file component:
export class BusinessUserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

```
    userData: Array<User> = [];
    userCounted: number;
    dataSource: BusinessUserSource;
    displayedColumns = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "active"];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
       constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private businessService: BusinessDashboardService,
        private auth: AuthService
      ) {
        this.businessId = this.auth.userData.business.id;
      }
    ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource = new BusinessUserSource(this.businessService);
this.dataSource.loadUsers(this.businessId, 1, 10);
this.dataSource.userData$.subscribe(
  (success: any) => {
    this.userData = success;
    console.log(this.userData);
  }
)
```

}

ngAfterViewInit() {

```
this.dataSource.userCount$.subscribe(
  (success: any) => {
    console.log(success);
    this.userCounted = success;
  }
);
```

}

}

Data source :

export class BusinessUserSource implements DataSource {

```
public usersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);
private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
public userCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
public userCount$ = this.userCount.asObservable();
public userData$ = this.usersSubject.asObservable();

constructor(private service: BusinessDashboardService) { }

loadUsers(
    businessId: number,
    pageIndex: number,
    pageSize: number) {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.service.allUsers(
        businessId,
        pageIndex,
        pageSize,
        ).pipe(
            catchError(() => of([])),
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
        )
        .subscribe((success: any) => {
            this.usersSubject.next(success.result.data);
            console.log(success);
            this.userCount.next(success.result.total);
        });
}

connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<User[]> {
    console.log("Connecting data source");
    return this.usersSubject.asObservable();
}

disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.usersSubject.complete();
    this.loadingSubject.complete();
}
```

}

Service:

```
allUsers(
  id: number,
  pageNumber,
  pageSize): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get("business-user/all/" + id + "?page_no=" + pageNumber + "&limit=" + pageSize)
    .pipe(map(
        (response: any) => response)
    );
}
```

AS you can see from the image from the user object in data array i want to iterate in table. please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIYFM.png

Comment: How I can reproduce the same issue? Can you provide your data in the Stackblitz?

Comment: it will take a while to create a stackblitz. i have put all my relevant code here

Comment: What `console.log(this.userData);` prints in the component?

Comment: data array from the response

Comment: Can you show us?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIYFM.png this data Array is printing as this.userData

Comment: In component.ts try this: `this.dataSource.userData$.subscribe(
  (success: any) => {
    this.userData = success.data;
   console.log(this.userData);
  }
)`

Comment: this.dataSource is the source here, not the userData, anyways usreData has the data array in it cause in DataSource class i have this this.usersSubject.next(success.result.data);

Comment: The problem is `this.dataSource` has not got the data properly. I would do `this.dataSource = new MatDataSource(success.data)`